# NoClassDefFoundError: java/time/LocalDateTime

Tags: java, maven, swing, java-time, localdatetime

I'm new with Java language. I have developed an example of a maven project and I have added the package LocalDateTime.

The problem is that when I run the program it appears me this error:
**NoClassDefFoundError: java/time/LocalDateTime**

I have added this line to import the package:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
```

I haven't added anything in the pom.xml file because with other packages imports I didn't add anything and it works properly.

Do I need to add some plugin or dependency in pom.xml file regarding to LocalDateTime?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: which java version are you using ? LocalDateTime is added in java 8 hopefully you are at least java 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a new api in Java.

Please try with java 8.

Comment: If this code is compiled with Java 7 or earlier, there will be a compiler error, not a NoClassDefFoundError. If this code is compiled with Java 8 or later and run with Java 7 or earlier, there would be a version error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @rob compile with java 8 set to source level 7 and run with 7 will give this message.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen thanks, I hadn't considered that scenario.

Answer (score 1):

The *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310 are built into Java 8 and later.

If you are stuck using Java 6 or Java 7, add the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) library to your project. This back-port brings much of the *java.time* functionality. By using a nearly identical API, later converting to *java.time* proper will be easy.

If doing Android development, Android 26+ has an implementation of *java.time* built in. For earlier Android, the latest tooling brings most of the functionality via *API desugaring*. If that does not work for you, add the *ThreeTenABP* library to your project.